# Unhandled promise rejection: Failed to load in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am trying to retrieve json data using Http with the help of service and component.
I have used observable and subscribe pattern for the same but when I am trying to access the data in component, I am getting below error :

```
Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load 

%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%7B%7Berror%7D%7D%3C/div%3E%
    0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%20*ngFor=%22let%20product%20of%20products%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%7B%7Bproduct.name%7D%7D%3C/li%3E%

0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/ul%3E%0A%20%20%20%20 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load %0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%7B%7Berror%7D%7D%3C/div%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%20*ngFor=%22let%20product%20of%20products%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%7B%7Bproduct.name%7D%7D%3C/li%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/ul%3E%0A%20%20%20%20
```

Below is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';


import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService{
    private _url:string="";
    constructor(private _http: Http){}

    getProducts(){
        return this._http.get('product-data.json')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(this._errorHandler);
    }

    _errorHandler(_error: Response){
        console.error( _error);
        return Observable.throw(_error || "Server Error");
    }

}
```

and my component is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './product';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';


@Component({
    selector:'product-list',

    templateUrl:`
       <ul *ngFor="let product of products">
            <li>{{product.name}}</li>

       </ul>
    `,
    providers:[ProductService]
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit{


    products : Product[];

    constructor(private _productService: ProductService){}
    ngOnInit(){
        this._productService.getProducts()
            .subscribe(products => this.products = products);

    }

}
```

Product model is:

```
export class Product
{
    name: string;    
}
```

I am not able to resolve the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying a template, not a `templateUrl`, so instead of doing this:

```
@Component({
    selector:'product-list',

    templateUrl:`
       <ul *ngFor="let product of products">
            <li>{{product.name}}</li>

       </ul>
    `,
    providers:[ProductService]
})
```

You should do this:

```
@Component({
    selector:'product-list',

    template:`
       <ul *ngFor="let product of products">
            <li>{{product.name}}</li>

       </ul>
    `,
    providers:[ProductService]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 constructor(private _productService: ProductService){}
    ngOnInit(){
        this._productService.getProducts()
            .subscribe(products => this.products = products,
                         err => {..do something here});

    }
```

your service returned an error and you didn't handle it